# Grails 4 , unable to build war file

Tags: grails

while upgrading grails from 2 to 4, unable to build war file.

i am using **grails test war**  command to build war.
but, it fails as...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':assetCompile'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  | Error Command [war] error: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: What operating system are you building this on?  Looks like you're hitting resource limits.

Comment: OS is Windows 10. FYI: when I add my js files in a Folder and place it under assets/javascripts. assetCompile fails. if not, i am able to build the war file. can't we place js files in  a folder ? they have to be under assets/javascripts/ ONLY?

Comment: I personally don't develop on Windows, so perhaps this is nonsense, but: any chance you have some shortcut in your folder?  This feels like you have more files to process than the system can handle, but I don't see that happening unless there's some sort of folder/shortcut infinite loop.  I can confirm from experience that you ARE allowed to have subfolders under assets/javascripts.

Comment: Grails 4 (Gradle system) is much more memory hungry when building than v2.